# Sending “keep alive message” even if the device is in the sleep mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a Foreground service that periodically sends a message to the server using `ScheduleTaskExecutor`. The interval is 15 seconds and cannot be longer.

I think I have read almost everything about the similar requirement here on SO, but still, on devices with Android 2.3.x, the executor stops executing after a device falls into the sleep mode – i.e. after pressing the power button.

I also tried using AlarmManager: [cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) but the result was exactly the same.

Is there something else I can try? I suspect it is a bug in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Foreground service that periodically sends a message to the server using ScheduleTaskExecutor. The interval is 15 seconds and cannot be longer.

If this is for a consumer device, this is ghastly behavior on the part of your app. You might wind up with a *negative* star rating on the Play Store.

> I think I have read almost everything about the similar requirement here on SO, but still, on devices with Android 2.3.x, the executor stops executing after a device falls into the sleep mode – i.e. after pressing the power button.

Perhaps you are not acquiring a `WakeLock`. And, depending on the connectivity options on the device in question, you may also need a `WifiLock` for reliable results.

> I also tried using AlarmManager: cwac-wakeful but the result was exactly the same.

`WakefulIntentService` is not designed for something running this frequently. You may as well grab your own `WakeLock` to hold forever, or until the battery runs out, or until the users of the device shoot you.

> Is there something else I can try?

Use logging (yours and the system's) to determine precisely what is and is not happening. Use **`adb shell dumpsys power`** to confirm the status of your `WakeLock`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It is a taxi application, each driver has the app in his phone, and the app must update the driver’s position so that customers know where the drivers are. After 10 minutes, a driver can be 20 kilometers from his last position... That’s why the update is so frequent. I cannot use logging, because it does not happen when the device is connected to IDE, even if it is in a sleep mode. The app will sure drain a battery, but the customer requirements are clear: get a position using GPS and send it to the server every 15 second...

Comment: That’s also the reason I use foreground service – to inform the user there is a battery draining app running on his phone.

Comment: @vitakot: "I cannot use logging, because it does not happen when the device is connected to IDE" -- logging occurs even when you are not connected to an IDE. When you *later* plug in the device, you can examine your logs. And that's even just using LogCat. If you maintain your own separate logs as files, you control what goes in those files, where they are stored, when they are removed, etc.